# python write file syntax error

Tags: python, string, syntax

just learning python and trying to write a script that allows the user to change lines in a text. For some reason I get this error when prompting the user to enter something for the line to be replaced:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "textedit.py", line 10, in 
    f.write(line1)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

and the script itself:

```
f = raw_input("type filename: ")
def print_text(f):
    print f.read()
current_file = open(f)
print_text(current_file)
commands = raw_input("type 'e' to edit text or RETURN to close the file")

if commands == 'e':
    line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
    f.write(line1)
else:
    print "closing file"
    current_file.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
f.write(line1)
```

into this:

```
current_file.write(line1)
```

The error occured, because you were accessing `f` as if it was a file, but it is only a file name given by the user. The opened file is stored in the `current_file` variable.

Additionally you are opening the file in read mode. Take a look at [`open()`'s documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open):

> `open(name[, mode[, buffering]])`
>
> The most commonly-used values of `mode` are **`'r'` for reading**, `'w'` for writing (truncating the file if it already exists), and `'a'` for appending (which on some Unix systems means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position). **If mode is omitted, it defaults to `'r'`.**

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing:

```
current_file.write(line1)
```

What happened? You stored the *filename* in `f` and then opened a file object with it, which you stored in `current_file`.

The error message was trying to tell you exactly that: `f` is a string. Strings don't have a `write` method. On line 10 you tried to call the method `write` on the object stored in the variable `f`. It can't work.

Learning to program will involve learning to read error messages. Don't worry. It gets easier as you go along.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
current_file = open(f)
```

to this one:

```
current_file = open(f, 'w')
```

and this:

```
f.write(line1)
```

to:

```
current_file.write(line1)
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting `'w'` mode. Maybe the downvote came before you added the second suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to `write` on `f` which is a string (contains a `raw_input()` result) while you should presumably write on a file. Also, it's considered more pythonic and a better practice opening a file using a `with` statement, so you'll be sure that your file will get closed in any possible case (unexpected errors included!):

python 3.x:

```
def print_from_file(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())

f = input("type filename: ")
with open(f, 'w') as current_file:
    print_from_file(f)
    commands = input("type 'e' to edit text or RETURN to close the file")
    if commands == 'e':
        line1 = input("line 1: ")
        current_file.write(line1)
    else:
        print("closing file")
```

python 2.x:

```
def print_from_file(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        print f.read()

f = raw_input("type filename: ")
with open(f, 'w') as current_file:
    print_from_file(f)
    commands = raw_input("type 'e' to edit text or RETURN to close the file")
    if commands == 'e':
        line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
        current_file.write(line1)
    else:
        print "closing file"
```